# event "transitionend" is calling a function twice in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

I am trying to get the exact height of the `divRef` only after the completion of the transition but the function `settingHeightForTransition` is running twice and setting the height twice.

Q.1: Why it's happening?

Q.2: How to solve it?

**code** -

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
  const [divHeight, setDivHeight] = useState(null);
  const [oneTime, setOneTime] = useState(false);
  const divRef = useRef(null);

  const handleBtnClick = () => {
    setClicked(!clicked);
    console.log("Div Height", divHeight);
    debugger;
    divRef.current.addEventListener(
      "transitionend",
      settingHeightForTransition
    );
    // why the function below this is called 2 times
    function settingHeightForTransition() {
      console.log("OneTime", oneTime);
      if (!oneTime) {
        console.log("settingHeightForTransition inside");
        setDivHeight(divRef.current.offsetHeight);
        setOneTime(true);
      }
    }
  };
  const styles = {
    open: {
      overflow: "hidden",
      transition: "max-height 1s ease-in-out",
      maxHeight: "50px",
      textAlign: "justify"
    },
    close: {
      overflow: "hidden",
      maxHeight: `${oneTime ? `${divHeight}px` : "1000px"}`,
      transition: "max-height 1s ease-in-out",
      textAlign: "justify"
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleBtnClick}>Click</button>
      <div style={clicked ? styles.close : styles.open} ref={divRef}>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
        since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
        scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
        centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
        essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
        of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
        with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
        of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-wind-0rqng?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems here

1. You are adding an event listener inside an event handler.
   This will cause more and more event listeners to be added every time you click. To fix this, add it only once on mount using a `useEffect`:

   ```
   useEffect(() => { 
     divRef.current.addEventListener(
       "transitionend",
        settingHeightForTransition
     );
    }, []);
   ```
2. The transition property itself it part of styles being applied. To fix this, always keep `transition` on the element using a class:

   ```
   <div
       className={"container " + (clicked ? "close" : "open")}
       style={{maxHeight: `${clicked? 0 : '200px'}`}}
   ```

   I recommend using classes for common styles. Also using something like StyledComponents will make it a lot easier to set computed styles.

[image: Edit hungry-meitner-qxhtl]

Comment: Hey, your answer completely  didn't work but it helped me to find the solution